# UVA 195 Anagram - Runtime Error - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the UVA 195 problem, but besides the accurate results in tests, the Online Judge returns "Runtime Error".

The function called "fatorial" calculates the factorial of a given number.
The function called "permutacoes" calculates the number of permutations of a given word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int fatorial (int a){
    int resultado = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++) resultado *= i;
    return resultado;
}

int permutacoes (string s){
    int t = s.length();

     //conta as repetições de cada letra
    int rep[t];
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++) rep[i]=1;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
        if(rep[i]==1){
            for(int j=(i+1); j<t; j++){
                if(s[i]==s[j]){
                    rep[i]++;
                    rep[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Calcula o número de permutações
    int fat = fatorial(t);
    int dividendo = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
            if(rep[i]>1) dividendo *= fatorial(rep[i]);
    }
    int resultado = fat/dividendo;
    return resultado;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    string s;
    cin>>n;

    while(n--){
        cin>>s;
        sort(s.begin(),s.end()); //Ordem inicial
        cout<<s<<endl; //Primeira saída

        int perm = permutacoes(s);
        //Todas as permutações, menos a primeira que já foi dada pelo sort
        while (--perm){
            next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end());
            cout<<s<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ you can use std::next_permutation. Initialize the string with std::sort.

Comment: 1) Why does it seem you're calling `next_permutation`, but also doing your own permutation function?  What's the purpose of `permutacoes`?   2) Your factorial function is flawed in that it will fail if the number given is negative.

Comment: Hi vz0, that's exactly what I was trying to do...

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie, 1) "permutacoes" calculates the number of permutations for the while loop with "next_permutation". 2)Yes, but the way it is called, the number is never negative. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in the way you are calculating the number of permutations. The program is maybe trying to divide some really big numbers, but one of those numbers is maybe overflowed (larger than maximum for `int`), and so incorrect.

Check your algorithm with word "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb" (10 letters 'a' and 10 letters 'b'). You should get 20!/(10!*10!)=184756 permutations, but I bet you will get some other value. Redirect the program output to a file, so that it finishes faster.

To solve the problem remove the function `permutacoes` and run the loop for as long as `next_permutation` is returning `true`. When `next_permutation` returns false there are no more permutations, and the word should be sorted as it was before the loop.